# Sealing edge between tub and tile

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, grout, caulk

I recently found a crack in the material that seals the tile to the tub edge, so I removed it in preparation to replace it. I originally thought that the edge was filled with grout, but in trying to remove it I found that it was soft, but its also rough like grout. So now I am a bit confused about what to replace it with.
Ideally we would like to replace with the same grout/caulk mixed stuff that I am removing, unless that is just not the right stuff. I have also heard from the above post that I want to use silicone caulk but I think that might be smooth and not ideal as far as looks. I also found this sanded silicone grout which I am kinda leaning towards [https://www.amazon.com/Color-Matched-Colorfast-Sanded-Sandstone/dp/B00X66X2D2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X66X2D2).

Anyone have an idea of what the stuff I am removing is and if it is the right material to replace with? If not is there something I can use that still has that rough grout like finish? Or do I have to use silicone caulk? Thanks for the help, I just dont want to have to repeat this in a couple weeks...

Answer (score 2):

Use silicone caulk. If you're having trouble with color matching, then check out Mapei's products. They make a bunch of colors. And be sure that the stuff you buy is younger than 1 year old.

Silicone caulk has stretchiness that makes it well suited for around tubs. The necessary stretchiness for your application is captured by "class 25" sealant (under ASTM C920), where any number larger than 25 would also be adequate. I don't see a class on your product's page and the "siliconized latex" sets off alarm bells in my mind. Doesn't look right for a bathtub, but I didn't look very hard.

Comment: Mapei's silicone grout is good, and in my experience well color matched to their hard grout, but you need to be careful that you don't buy expired product if you get it from the usual big home stores. I got some expired stuff about a year ago and it just never set - had to scrape it all out and start over. Mapei customer support was very apologetic and helpful though, replacing all the product as well as throwing in a few extras for my trouble.

Comment: @brhans, Jesus. Thanks for the tip. I think you probably just saved me from some future grief. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, the stuff that isn't pure (I guess aside from the added coloring) silicone has a tendency to harden over the years—at which point it's no better than grout.

Comment: @Huesmann, I found https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=124310. I guess the "neutral curing" type refuses to cure eventually. I guess I should find that smell of vinegar comforting instead of annoying. There's probably some caulk sniffing in my future to check whether an expired tube should get trashed.